# Common source amplifier with current mirror active load

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos

I am reading about common source amplifier with a current-mirror active load from the book Analog Integrated Circuit Design by Tony Chan Carusone, David Johns, Kenneth Martin.
I am confused by the yellow sentence below:

**For a fixed bias drain current,ID , the effective overdrive voltage is reduced by increasing the device width W.**

From the formula that relates between Veff and W/L it is clear that Veff is reduced if W is increased. However, from the circuit on the picture, the basing network for Q1 is not shown. 
How to make the basing network for Q1 so that Veff of Q1 decreases when W increases?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias current is set by the current source Ibias, it is mirrored to the active load Q2 and the current through Q1 has to be about equal to the current delivered by Q2.

This is not done by some sort of bias network but through application of feedback. Imagine this stage as the second stage of an OpAmp as shown below.
[image]

The CS Stage consists of M3 and M8, biased by M1.

In order to use this Opamp feedback is required. For example OUT could be fed back to IN-. The first stage of the OpAmp will take care of the biasing. The voltage at the gate of M8 will be such, that OUT is almost equal to IN+.

Comment: Thank you. So according to the yellow sentence, the current source generated by M3 is fixed or constant. If we increase the width of M8 then the voltage at the gate of M8 will be decreased. Is this only correct if there is an external feedback?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: So could you explain the process from W of M8 increases to the gate voltage of M8 decreases through external bias?
When W8 of M8 increases, how Vout changes and what happens next leading to gate voltage of M8 decreases?

Comment: W of M8 goes up, Vout decreases, is fed back to IN-, current trough M4 increaes, current through M5 decreases, the voltage at the gate of M8 goes down.

Comment: Thanks. For W of M8 goes up, Vout decreases, how did you explain it? Did you base on the Id - Vds of MOS with different W plot?

Comment: A wider transistor can sink more current, Vds has to go down for a constant Id.

Comment: Please check if my understanding correctly. Wider transistor will sink more current, so the current through output resistance rds (Ibias - current through transistor) will decrease. So Vo decreases.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to ask other questions relating to this circuit.
Without feedback are the voltage levels at the Vout node and at the gate of M8 at undefined levels/values?

Comment: The circuit is usually designed to operate in or close to a operating point where all transistors are in saturation and high gain is possible even under open loop conditions. However, due to device mismatch and thermal effects this operating point is not stable and some feedback is required. In any case the input of the OpAmp has to be at a defined potential, i.e. the input terminals must not be left floating.

Comment: I heard that in open loop the voltage at Vout node can have any values. Does this because mismatch, thermal effects or internal structure of transistors?

Comment: It does not have a well-defined stable value, because of the reasons you've just mentioned.

Comment: So, assume that there are no device mismatch, thermal effects,...then how to calculate DC operating point Vout value here?

Comment: It will depend on the current mismatch and the output resistance of the two transistors in the output stage.

Comment: Let's assume that there is no current mismatch as well. And let's say that the current through output stage is Iout, how can I calculate Vout? THank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45832/discussion-between-mario-and-anhnha).